# Crear una calculadora usando ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, asp

Estoy realizando un pequeño ejercicio de operaciones consumiendo un Web Service, pero no encuentro la manera de poder mostrar el resultado en la vista, no estoy usando Model.

Controlador

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int primero, int segundo)
    {
        // Creación de un objeto de referencia del servicio web  
        ServiceReference1.CalculatorSoapClient multi = new ServiceReference1.CalculatorSoapClient();

        // llama y almacena el resultado del servicio web en la variable  
        var multiplicac = multi.Multiply(primero, segundo);
        return View();
    }
```

Vista

```
 @Html.Label("PRIMER NUMERO");
@Html.Editor("primero")
@Html.Label("SEGUNDO NUMERO");
@Html.Editor("segundo")
@Html.Label("la respuesta es : " );
<input type="submit" name="Calcular" value="Calcualar" />
```

cuando hago la operación en el controlador si me muestra el resultado,correctamente.Como puedo hacer en la vista para que me muestre el resultado, o hay otra manera de hacer una operacion.

[image: resultado]

Comment: Saludos Daniel, percibo que estás aprendiendo, esto te ayudará: http://fredyfx.com/post/tutorial-microsoft-webmatrix-sintaxis-razor/ y http://fredyfx.com/post/material-workshop-aspnet-mvc-5/

Answer (score 1):

puedes pasar el valor a la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
public ActionResult NombreView()
{
  ViewData["multiplicac"] = multi.Multiply(primero, segundo);
        return View();
}
```

y luego en la vista lo puedes usar haciendo:

```
@Html.Encode(ViewData["multiplicac"].ToString())
```

Comment: ya lo pude resolver, de otra manera. podrían ver el resultado en la actualizacion